# Do you have to dispose the following SharePoint objects?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I wanted to make sure there's no memory leak in SharePoint so do I need to call dispose for the following SharePoint objects once I'm done? I'm thinking I shouldn't have to since I'm not creating new and using GetCurrent(), but with SharePoint it's hard to tell.

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SiteActions siteActions 
    = SiteActions.GetCurrent(this.Page);

Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.PageStateActionButton psab 
    = PageStateActionButton.GetCurrent(this.Page);

Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPRibbon ribbon 
    = Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPRibbon.GetCurrent(this.Page);
```

Comment: [Best Practices: Using Disposable Windows SharePoint Services Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx)